# Why is System.Data.SQLite always returning False from queries on bool columns?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Here is my code:

```
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM rosters WHERE team_id = " + teamID;
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, db.GetConnection());
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            if ((bool)reader["in_lineup"])
            {
                lineup.Add(player);
            }

        }
```

The problem I am having is with the last if statement. "in_lineup" is a boolean column, and some of the records have it set to true, but the if statement is never entered, and reader["in_lineup"] is always false. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Changed code sample to make my problem more clear.

Comment: is your teanmID a legitimate value and your query returning any values? set breakpoint and see the results.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure then. I'd have to step through the code, sorry. Put in a var inLineup = reader["in_lineup"] on the line before and see what is happening there. Good luck.

Comment: See here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean

Comment: @kuujinbo thanks man without your link i would have spent hours and hours dealing with this.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that SQLite returns either 0 or 1 for a Boolean value. C# (unlike C++) does not convert from an integer to a Boolean.
It might thus be better to rewrite the test:

```
if ((bool)reader["in_lineup"])
```

as

```
if((int)reader["in_lineup"] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against Object based getter as in `Reader["colName"]`.
I've always used strongly typed getters knowing the column index as in

```
Reader.GetBoolean(3)
```

This has the added benefit of detecting errors in the table layout/type affinity.

EDIT: As a side note, we've added extension methods to deal with DBNull return. for example:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Returns a string from a column
    /// This extension exists because SQLite doesn't recognize null as a valid string but C# does
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Source"></param>
    /// <param name="Column"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static String xGetString(this System.Data.Common.DbDataReader Source, Int32 Column)
    {
        if (Source.IsDBNull(Column))
            return null;

        if (Source.GetFieldType(Column) != typeof(String))
            throw new Core.DatabaseException(
                String.Format("Column `{0}` ({1}) is not of type String. Type is {2}.",
                Source.GetName(Column), Column, Source.GetFieldType(Column).Name));

        return Source.GetString(Column);
    }
```

Comment: Good to know this Is possible.